# Write records to a file when 500 Records reached or 2 mins of Time Passed from the previous file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, filewriter

I have a scenario, where I have a worker method (DoWork()) which is getting called by the web service continuously.

This worker method writes the data to a file using the (writeToFile()) and I need to write this to a file under 2 conditions

a) when the number of records reached in 500 OR

b) 2 minutes has been passed from the previous file been written

my sample code is as follows:

```
public override void DoWork()
{
//-- This worker method is called continuously by the webservice 
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
int count =0;
//--- Some code that writes the RawData
list1.Add(rawData);
If(list1.Count<=500)
{
list2=list1;
count = WriteToFile(list2);

}
}

public static int WriteToFile(List<string> list)
{
//-- The writing of File Should happen when 500 records reached OR 2 mins passed.

// ---- Logic for writing the list file using the Streamwriter is working fine

}
```

I need a logic check if

> 500 records reached in the List OR
>   2 mins passed from the previous
>   file generated,

only then the file writing should happen.

Thanks
:)

Comment: Why is `DoWork` overridden? What does "continuously called" mean? In your snippet, `list1` is declared twice, I guess one of them is supposed to declare `list2` ...

Comment: Where is "rawData" coming from? If 500 items are exceeded, shall _all_ be written or only (the first) 500?

Comment: @Fildor: continuously means in a threaded manner || yes the second list is suppose to be list2 (typo error)

Answer (score 0):

To make it a little more readable, I'd use a little helper, here...
Time check:

```
class TimeCheck{
    private TimeSpan timeoutDuration;
    private DateTime nextTimeout;

    // Default = 2 minutes.
    public TimeCheck(): this(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))
    {}

    public TimeCheck( TimeSpan timeout ){
         this.timeoutDuration= timeout;
         this.nextTimeout = DateTime.Now + timeoutDuration;
    }

    public bool IsTimeoutReached => DateTime.Now >= nextTimeout; 

    public void Reset(){
        nextTimeout = DateTime.Now + timeoutDuration;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// on class level
const int MAXITEMS = 500;
private Lazy<TimeCheck> timecheck = new Lazy<TimeCheck>( () => return new TimeCheck() );
private List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
private readonly object Locker = new object();

public override void DoWork()
{
    lock(Locker){
        // ... add items to list1

        // Write if a) list1 has 500+ items or b) 2 minutes since last write have passed
        if( list1.Count >= MAXITEMS || timecheck.Value.IsTimeoutReached )
        {
            WriteToFile(list1);
            list1.Clear();     // assuming _all_ Items are written.
            timecheck.Value.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

**Attention**:

- If code is called by multiple threads, you need to make sure it's thread safe. I used `lock` *which will create a bottleneck*. You may want to figure out a more sophisticated manner, but this answer concentrates on the condition requirements.
- Above snippet assumes, `list1` is not accessed elsewhere.